# Bootstrap link button and button not the same width. How to fix?

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap, width

I added width property to bootstrap buttons. However, it did not make  `<a class="btn" />` the same width as `<button class="btn" />`. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b9T4/).

This is in Chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resetting the left and right `padding` to zero helps but leaves the link button 2px wider.

This is because chrome's user agent applies `box-sizing: border-box` to `button` elements which means the `padding` will be included in the `width` and not in addition to it.

Setting `box-sizing: content-box` in your class fixes this 2px difference as well.

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6b9T4/9/)**.

Comment: Thanks! But the link is still about 1-bit longer. I think I will use the `<button />` version and add click event to it.